# (C) - How would one compare 2 txt files REQUESTS.txt and AVAILABLE.txt, separating each str read into a (STR6, STR3, STR3, INT) formatted Structure?

Tags: c

I have been working on this program for over a week with no breakthrough. The questions states as follows:
A ​disc​ ​file​ ​‘REQUESTS.TXT’​ ​contains​ ​airline​ ​flight​ ​data formatted​ 
`​(STR6,​ ​STR3,​ ​STR3,​ ​INT)​`.

```
Example:​  
AA1011​SFx​LAx​​34​ ​(American Airlines​ ​1010,​ ​SF​ ​to​ ​LA,​ ​34​ ​seats)   
W0924​DNV​DFW​​101​ ​(Western​ ​0924,​ ​DNV​ ​to​ ​DFW,​ ​101​ ​seats)
```

Another​ ​file​ ​‘AVAILABL.TXT’​ ​contains​ ​an​ ​unspecified​ number​ ​of​ ​reservation​ request​ ​records formatted​ ​identically​ ​as​ ​described​ ​above​ ​except​ ​the​ Seats​ ​Available​ ​field​ ​is​ ​a​ ​Seats​ ​Requested field.

Guidelines:

1. Read reservation flights and process requests. If the request can be fullfilled (i.e.. it is in AVAILABL and REQUESTS) then print "Reservation Processed", otherwise print "Reservation Denied".
2. Print out flight data file before and after reservations are processed, ordered by flight ID in a four(4) column format.
3. Print an overall outcome report for all processed.(Present totals for the number of requests satisfied and denied)

I have tried a few different approaches.. I tried to split up the first STR6 by isalpha/isdigit and combine them to make the FlightID (AA + 1011). Proceeded to try to then split up the remaining characters between STR3 and STR3 via isalpha + for loop. And lastly, I tried to take the last 3+ digits for the # of seats during each for loop iteration and multiply the first digit by 100(for a 3-digit value) or 10(for a 2-digit value), adding it to a running total for availSeats(INT). This, at least I thought so, would produce a

```
AA+1011 = AA1011(STR6)  //  W+0924 = W0924(STR6)
SFx(STR3)               //  DNV(STR3)
LAx(STR3)               //  DFW(STR3)
(3*10)+(4*1) = 34(INT)  //  (1*100)+(0*10)+(1*1) = 101(INT)
```

All of this stored within a Struct Array.
i.e...
`FlightData Flight;`       ............................................`FlightData Flight;`
`Flight[0].flightID = AA1011;`    .........................`Flight[1].flightID = W0924;`
`Flight[0].fromCity = SFx;`    ...............................`Flight[1].fromCity = DNV;`
`Flight[0].toCity = LAx;`    ..................................`Flight[1].toCity = DFW;`
`Flight[0].seatsAvail = 34;`    .............................`Flight[1].seatsAvail = 101;`

I am really at a loss right now and have no other way to progress other than searching up different techniques/methods to use to make this work. I am a beginner clearly and will continue to practice and progress in C, but if anyone could provide me with a push in the right direction on how one would execute this via .txt into a Struct would be amazing. Also, if anyone has another method they used to solve this problem I would love to analyze it. Thanks!

(This is my first post, I spent a lot of time formatting it to be clear on Stackoverflow, so If i messed up in areas some constructive critisism would be useful! This applies to my posting and my coding practices. Thanks again!)

EDIT: The question I am asking here is how to successfully take a string such as AA1011SFxLAx34 and turn it into a Structure like the above diagram. It must also work for the second string W0924DNVDFW101 which has only 1 Char in its ID. (rather than two in AA1011). Im not sure what else I am supposed to edit after reading the guidelines.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and modify the question

Answer (score 0):

I consider this a home work question, so I answer according to
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Find a tutorial on C, work through it.
Then take a HelloWorld, modify it in small steps to approach your goal in steps from working program to working program. This way you should at least get to being able to read text from a file and print it.
Then learn to store parts of what you print into basic variables.
Then learn about structures.
And so on.

This way you will get quite close to the solution.
If it is not completely what you need show the code you have here at that point and ask a specific question about the first problem explaining what you suspect the problem to be. Show code which has exactly that one problem and makes it visible and has not other warnings (using at least e.g. `gcc -Wall mycode`).

Fix with the help of commments/answers you receive, repeat.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to at least write something. I am currently in Java400 and this example was given to me by an old instructor in 2015 when I was in VB. I created this problem in VBC and have since done the same in C++ and Java. After discovering some of my favorite programs were written in C in ways I was unaware of, I went back to my OneDrive, and found a stack of old lab projects. This is one of them. It is not homework, and I do know the basics of C, but that is it. I am hoping someone can provide me with some actual guidance as that is what I was told this site was for.